# Cannot Delete ArangoDB Collection: filesystem full

Tags: arangodb

When using the web interface and AQL query interface, I'm having issues removing a rather large collection. I get a "filesystem full" error when I try to delete the collection. I've been creating and truncating collections several times in this DB (and sometimes they are rather large), and I think I may not have been doing it properly. The disk space is all used up, event though the number of documents in the collections that are viewable does not line up with the disk usage. I suspect that after each truncation/deletion of a collection, the disk space has not been properly freed up. Right now the DB seems bricked as I cannot remove collections or insert more documents. Is there a way to fix this without rebuilding?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.